# Reading data from /dev/tty port in PHP application fails to error reading

Tags: php, apache, serial-port, tty, infrared

I have USB IR module in connected to a tty port, and I can read/write data from/to it fine.

Now I'm trying to run a PHP application that would read data from that port, but for some reason my PHP script on Apache can't seem to read the serial port. I get complaint "error accessing"
The user (www-data) has access to dialup group (in /etc/group):

```
...
dialout:x:20:jlumme,www-data
...
```

And if I switch over to www-data user (su www-data), I am able to successfully run the program from the same folder where it resides (same folder with PHP script).
Access rights to the tty should also be ok:

```
>ls -l /dev/tty
...
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166, 0 2012-05-03 19:10 ttyACM0
...
```

I'm out of ideas what to try..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like all I had to do was to re-boot the linux board, and now it worked ok.
I'm not sure what went wrong before, possibly re-starting Apache could have done the trick.

Anyhow, just making sure proper user rights have access to /dev/tty seems to be the answer!

Comment: I know this is super old, but restarting apache worked for me after adding www-data to the dialout group:

    `gpasswd -a www-data dialout`
    `service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php
system('whoami');
?>
```

to see if the script is run as www-data.

Comment: Hi blues,
Thank you for reply.

This was indeed how I first found out which is the user that runs Apache.. Sorry, I should have been more clear about this in the OP.

Just to see, I also set read rights to all (a+r), but the problem didnt seem to go away..